# Efficiently create a dictionary and read input querying the dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

### Problem I'm trying to solve

I'm trying to solve [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps) using Python.

### Solution I'm using

```
N = int(raw_input().strip())
phoneBook = {}
for i in range(N):
    name, number = raw_input().strip().split()
    phoneBook[name] = number

s = str(raw_input().strip())
while True:
    if s in phoneBook.keys():
        print "{}={}".format(s, phoneBook[s])
    else:
        print "Not found"
    try:
        s = str(raw_input().strip())
    except EOFError:
        break
```

### Problem with my solution

The problem comes in the later test cases where there are 100,000 entries into the dictionary, and then an unknown number of queries against the dictionary. The site is saying that the code times out while processing, which seems to imply that there's a more efficient manner in doing this.

### Question

How, if at all, can I decrease the complexity of this algorithm so that it runs faster?

Comment: `phoneBook.keys()` creates the list of keys each time the loop runs. You could try `if phoneBook.get(s): print` or ignore that step and just `try/except` which may be faster.

Comment: I'd think using `for line in sys.stdin:` would be easier; then you could drop the `try: ...` and the duplicate `raw_input()` lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by doing `if s in phoneBook.keys():` you're not taking advantage of python dictionary search (in python 2, `keys()` returns a `list`)

just do:

```
if s in phoneBook:
```

to enable dictionary search performance

Aside: `raw_input().strip().split()` could be replaced by `raw_input().split()` since `strip` already discards blank fields.

I would get all the data in a dict comprehension like this (python 2):

```
phoneBook = dict(raw_input().split() for _ in xrange(N)) # xrange because it's faster in python 2
```

or in python 3:

```
phoneBook = dict(input().split() for _ in range(N))
```

Comment: Such a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: `raw_input` is safer and `input` would evaluate your data so it wouldnt work. Except in python 3 where you must use `input` at all times.